# An odd determinant and a parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, determinant

> In a matrix of size $n$, there are exactly $m$ odd elements, the rest of them being even. Find all the values of $0\le m \le n^2$ such that the determinant of the matrix is odd.

My first idea was to begin from the formula $\det A = \sum_{\sigma \in S(n)} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)a_{1\sigma(1)}\cdots a_{n\sigma(n)}$, but I didn't know how to grasp the solution from here. Can you help me?

Comment: My first idea would be to try it with $n = 1$, then with $n = 2$ to get an idea of how the oddness condition happens at all.  Then look at $n = 3$ to verify the ideas have some chance of working as $n$ increases.  Can you solve the problem in the $n = 1$ and $n = 2$ cases?

Comment: Of course! I should have mentioned it in the post. For $n=1$ we have $m=1$, and for $n=2$ we have $m=3$($m$ could not be 2, even if there was one matrix that satisfied, because we can find a configuration that didn't have the determinant odd).

Comment: I think it may help to note that you may as well look only at matrices with entries $0,1$ since changing any entry my $2$ doesn't affect the parity of the determinant.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes, you are right.

Comment: In view of your reply to @EricTowers I am not sure that I understand your question. Is it (i) Find for each $n$ the possible values of $m$ such that there is a matrix with exactly $m$ odd entries whose determinant is odd; or is it (ii) Find for each $n$ the possible values of $m$ such that every matrix with exactly $m$ odd entries has odd determinant.

Comment: The statement of the problem is the one I wrote, but I understood it as (ii), as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You have explained that what you want to find are those $m$ for which every $n\times n$ integer matrix with exactly $m$ odd entries has odd determinant.

For $n>2$ there are no such $m$.

To see this first note that $m\geqslant 2n$ is impossible: the matrix with $1$'s in the first two rows and $m-2n$ $1$'s anywhere else has determinant zero.

But $m<2n$ is also impossible: consider a matrix with $m$ $1$'s placed anywhere in the first two rows, and all other entries $0$, and note that this has determinant $0$ (since there are more than $2$ rows).

As in my comment I think "Find for each $n$ the possible values of $m$ such that there is a matrix with exactly $m$ odd entries whose determinant is odd" is a lot more interesting.

Comment: Yes, you are right and now that I saw your solution and thought a bit about it, I must have misunderstood what the problem wanted. Do you have any clues about the (i) interpretation as you mentioned in the comment?

Comment: Well I computed what happens for $n=3$ and got that the possibilities were $m=3,4,5,6,7$ where for $m=4,5$ there were solutions that were strongly different in the sense that row/col permutations didn't carry one to another. It seems to me to be hard.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!